# Load plain text inline in Markdown in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I know you can 'import' text or code in Jupyter notebook cells with `%load file_name.ext` but that pastes the entirety in the cell. Is there a way to load a blog of text inside a Markdown cell at the desired location?

What I'm looking for is this:

```
This is some custom text from my current notebook and because I share the same example across multiple notebooks, I'd like to re-use it and not copy-paste it everywhere:

<<<insert contents of some_file.md>>>

And then I can continue with a text that's only visible in this notebook.
```

That way I do not have to repeat myself and have a single place where I can edit these shared bits of text (or code).

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21780837/8703627

Comment: It's a possibility, but I'd not like to have all text stored in separate files. Ideally, I only store the _shared_ text/code in separate files. The rest can live within the notebook.